# What is the word or term for forgetting what you’re doing while doing it

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

While running downstairs to do something important, I notice how sunny it is outside, and by the time I reach the bottom of the stairs I forget why I ran down the stairs in the first place! Or I’m in the middle of a sentence trying to explain something, and all of a sudden forget what I’m trying to explain. I’m not asking about tip of the tongue or an inability to remember someone’s name, because the thought or names were already thought of a few seconds earlier.  I usually remember a few seconds or minutes later, and sometimes it takes much longer, or I don’t remember at all. I’m pretty sure this happens to everybody; what is the term or word that describes this? It, not Lethologica or Lethonomia.

There are a lot of good suggestions to replace the term, brain farts, like a mental lapse or senior moment, but I’m looking for a more formal term like Lethologica or Lethonomia.

A sentence example would be: I’ve experienced [word/term] throughout my life on occasion, but the recent frequency has me concerned something is wrong or I need to change something in my life.

Or: I’ve experienced a lot of [word/term]  lately so I know I need to get more sleep.

Comment: Senior moment…  although I don’t like it much.

Comment: That's actually a good question, which, I don't think, the other thread really addresses.  Years ago, when I was about 40, a clerk at the hardware store up the road asked me what I needed.  I couldn't remember.  So, not a "senior moment", but, perhaps, the twenty minute walk there on a nice summer day, which got me to thinking about other things.  Now, if I recall, the "Amazing Kreskin" did a bit about tapping people on the shoulder, them forgetting what they were supposed to recall.

Comment: @G.Rem - You don’t think *mental lapse* is adequate?